discontinuity of double layer potential kernel on $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \Gamma$ and $\vert x- y \vert >0$
Background
There is a result in [SV02] that
Lemma 2.5.1 Assume that $\Gamma $ is a $C^1$ smooth Jordan curve. Suppose that $g(x,y)$ satifies
(1) Function $g(x,y)$ is continuous  in the set $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \Gamma $ and $x \neq y$.
(2) Weak singularity: there exists $\nu \in(0,1)$ such that for a sufficiently small $\delta >0 $ we have
$$
\vert g(x,y) \vert \leq c \vert x-y \vert^{-\nu}, \quad \textrm{when} \quad 0 < \vert x-y \vert \leq \delta.
$$
and let $u \in C(\Gamma)$ . Then the function
$$
(Gu)(x):= \int_{\Gamma} g(x,y) u(y) d\Gamma_y \quad \textrm{for} \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$
is continuous in  $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Question
Let $\Gamma $ be a $C^2$ smooth Jordan curve, $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \Gamma = \Omega_{-} \cup \Omega_{+}$, $\Omega_{+}$ the unbounded domain, $n_y$ be the unit normal at point $y \in \Gamma$ directed into $\Omega_{+}$. We notice that the kernel
$$
k(x,y) := \frac{\partial}{\partial n_y} \frac{1}{2\pi} \log \frac{1}{\vert x-y \vert} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{n_y \cdot (x-y)}{\vert x -y \vert^2} 
$$
is weakly singular on $\Gamma \times \Gamma$ and the corresponding
double layer potential admit a jump when point $x$ approach the curve $\Gamma$, thus, the kernel is discontinuous on $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \Gamma $ and $\vert x - y \vert >0$ because of the lemma above.
Now what is the discontinuity?
Reference
[SV02]  Jukka Saranen, Gennadi Vainikko. Periodic Integral and Pseudodifferential Equations with Numerical Approximation. Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 2002.
